# Accordion Style multi tier list menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, html-lists

I have looked around and have yet to find a solution to this problem. I have a list menu with markup like so

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Category #1
      <ul>
        <li>Item #1</li>
        <li>Item #2</li>
        <li>Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category #2
      <ul>
        <li>Item #1</li>
        <li>Item #2</li>
        <li>Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category #3
      <ul>

        <li>Item #1</li>
        <li>Item #2</li>
        <li>Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category #4
      <ul>
        <li>Item #1</li>
        <li>Item #2</li>
        <li>Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is make it so that the menu is entirely horizontal, when you hover over a category it will slide out the Items next to it.
Visual example here
[image]

Its quite important that it is built on a structured list and as I said as far as I can tell, none of the accordions I have checked so far support this feature.
Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there links in the lite items? If so, you could try something like this:

```
li ul {
    display:none;
}
li, ul, a {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    outline:1px solid;
}
li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

This does not include the "slide out" functionality, but shows that you will probably need a separate element around the text just before each nested ul. (The overall styling here is of course just proof of concept, feel free to skip the outline e.g. ;)

Comment: Cheers, I was trying to do it with jQuery but this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

THere is a horizontal accordian implementation here

```
http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html
```

Horizontal or vertical it depends how you float the elements.

I found the example from the below location

```
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-amazing-jquery-accordions
```

Comment: @alexander , there is one more here http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion.15528.html , but the above one was good with video explanation too

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

.menu ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.menu li{float:left;top:0;}
.menu li ul{display:none;top:0;}
.menu li:hover ul{display:inline;top:0;}

will do the trick for creating what you want, but the problem is not in the creating, but in the using. It will be for practical purposes - jittery to hover from child to another parent on the right, and unusable/unselectable links if you make it a multi-level beyond the code you have pasted. The element being hovered will move out of position (and thus out of hover) and lose its styling and focus in some cases, like for example, hovering from #Item 3 to #Category 2 in your example will make item 3 lose focus, and thus Category 1 lose focus and thus #Items 1,2 and 3 will become invisible and Category 2 will come in the place of Item 1.

This can still work, if you have only one level of sub-links. For more than one level, the nature of the menu is such that many links will be inaccessible, because they will change position/hide before they can be clicked.

To still make it work somehow, you can use css3 and/or javascript to create slow animation of the appearing and disappearing of links and perhaps someone with quick reflexes can select some.....

Not such a great idea.

Might be better to create an accordian type menu and use clicks to toggle expanding and collapsing rather than hover.

PS: I havent actually tested the code I gave you. You may need to test and tweak.

PPS: The "top:0" for the anyway "display:none" is because if you end up using transitions, you don't want it jumping out of place as it fades. Optional.

PPPS: I'm not saying don't do it, just telling you what to expect. Of course, you can still use that disorienting collapse thing to your advantage by making it look like an expressive/attitude thing. .... heavy looking images for category backgrounds, and coiled spring for item backgrounds....? You get the train of thought?